# How to use counters in a redis key?

Tags: redis

Is there a way to do this in redis ?

```
SET counter 0
INCR counter
SET KEY:{counter} "Content of line 1"
INCR counter
SET KEY:{counter} "Different content of line 2"
```

My example code should be substituted (i.e., transformed at runtime by the redis-cli) into:

```
SET counter 0
INCR counter
SET KEY:1 "Content of line 1"
INCR counter
SET KEY:2 "Different content of line 2"
etc.
```

My problem is NOT how to auto-increment the counter.
My problem is syntax: How to include a generic {wildcard} into something like:

```
SET keyname:{currentcounter} "value" ...
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot !

bernie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using redis 2.6+ then you can use lua scripting along with EVAL command like the following:

```
eval "local c = redis.call('incr', KEYS[1]); 
      return redis.call('set', KEYS[2] .. ':' .. c, ARGV[1])"
      2 counter KEY "Content of line 1"
```

I broke it up onto multiple lines to make it easier to read.

**EDIT**
Sorry, I was away on business for a few days.  Here is a sample showing that it works.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> flushdb
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> eval "local c = redis.call('incr', KEYS[1]); return redis.call('set', KEYS[2] .. ':' .. c, ARGV[1])" 2 counter KEY "Content of line 1"
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "KEY:1"
2) "counter"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> get counter
"1"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> get KEY:1
"Content of line 1"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> eval "local c = redis.call('incr', KEYS[1]); return redis.call('set', KEYS[2] .. ':' .. c, ARGV[1])" 2 counter KEY "Content of the next thing"
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "KEY:1"
2) "KEY:2"
3) "counter"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> get counter
"2"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> get KEY:2
"Content of the next thing"
```

Comment: "SET counter 0" for a definite starting point. When I then run your example I get an OK. "GET counter" then replies "1". Fine.
But "GET KEYS:1" and GET KEYS[1] reply (nil). How do I retrieve the value for KEY:1 resp. KEY[1]? Thanks! bernie

Comment: Hello sberry,

Would you be so nice to follow-up my question as I would very much like to use your approach? Unfortunately, I have no clue about Lua. Do I have to write a Lua script to retrieve the value from redis or can I use normal redis commands? If the second choice then how would I query redis in your example?

Thanks a lot!

bernie

Comment: @BernieReiter: I added sample output run from redis-cli.

Comment: I still don't understand the KEYS[1] and the KEYS[2] part of the Lua statement I have no clue about Lua but so what. I do like the result and I can tinker around with the Lua statement. Approved and question closed.  
Thanks a lot for your help!  bernie

Answer (score 0):

Nope, SET/GET commands don't support this.

You can do similar things using LUA scripts in redis, or even simpler; you can issue the commands as redis expect them using trivial programming/scripting

Comment: > SET/GET commands don't support this.
  
Are there other redis commands like lists or hashes which do support this kind of usage of an automatically incremented counter?  

> using trivial programming/scripting...  
If I do this then I have to call redis-cli twice each time I insert a new value. Once to retrieve the current value of counter and once to store the new value. That is exactly what I what to avoid. Any other tips or tricks?  
  
Thanks!  
  
bernie